# How to backup all docker container logs

Tags: docker, jenkins, logging, containers, docker-logs

I am quite new in docker and I don't know if this has been asked before. Is it possible to backup all `docker container logs` without using volumes for each container? We are using docker on a remote machine (mostly using `jenkins`)

Right now I am running multiple `containers` and multiple `docker-compose` on my remote machine. I want to save the logs (with a `retention period` of `7 days`) for future use.

Is there any available `images` that can help me with this one? We initially use `elk-stack` + `filebeat` but they consume too much resources. Now we are just use `dozzle` to view logs remotely.

Answer (score 1):

After some deliberation, I just did the following commands to backup my logs:

```
docker ps -a --format {{.Names}} //to get names of docker containers
for each container 
    docker logs container_name > container_name_date.log

forfiles /p <logs location> /s /m *.log* /c \"cmd /c Del @path\" /d -7" //to delete >7 day old log files
```

Now I am running this script via jenkins pipeline as a daily cron job